# Feedzirra is not updating the article content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, feedzirra

I'm using Feedzirra to get some rss content. This content can be updated by a third person. In my controller I have the following code:

```
RSS_FEED = "http://xxxxxxxx.wordpress.com/category/my_category/feed/"

my_feed = Feedzirra::Feed.fetch_and_parse RSS_FEED

@my_feed_text = my_feed.entries.first.sanitize! if ( my_feed && my_feed != 0 )
```

Eveything works fine until someone update the content of the only article in the **my_category** category...I'm getting the old content again and again. I try to put the RSS_FEED url in a browser and I get the new content...but in my application (also tried in rails console) I keep getting the old content.

Any hint?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the problem was with the refresh of wordpress rss. Today is working fine, the change is visible within 5-10 minutes.